# Link_to object stop working on dynamic route segments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

i have routes nested in a scope like following:

```
scope ':school_domain' do
  resources :users
  ...
end
```

`link_to('view', current_user)` stops working but when i remove scope or add `defaults: {school_domain: 'some_default_val'}` to scope, link_to starts working again. Please let me know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of RnD i have been able to resolve that issue by just declaring the following method as `private` in `application_controller.rb` file.

```
def default_url_options options={}
  options.merge(school_domain: current_user.school.name)
end
```